# Blazor - single page with OSM

Tags: c#, .net-core, leaflet, blazor

I am trying to create a simple web map using Blazor and OSM using [BlazorLeaflet](https://github.com/Mehigh17/BlazorLeaflet) NuGet package. A single page that will have 100% covered with OSM map. When width and height values are fixes to certain values all work well. However, when I try to set width and height attributes to 100% page is completely blank.

MainLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@Body
```

Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using System.Drawing
@using BlazorLeaflet
@using BlazorLeaflet.Models
@using BlazorWebMap.Data
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<div id="map">
    <LeafletMap Map="_map" />
</div>

<style>
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

@code
{
    private Map _map;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _map = new Map(jsRuntime)
        {
            Center = _startAt,
            Zoom = 12.2f
        };

        _map.OnInitialized += () =>
        {
            _map.AddLayer(new TileLayer
            {
                UrlTemplate = "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                Attribution = "&copy; <a href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors",
            });
    };
    }

    private LatLng _startAt = new LatLng(53.13344f, 23.15026f);
}
```

I know that is possible to do it by using only [HTML](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/make-your-leafletjs-map-full-screen.html) but I would like to do it in Blazor and is a starting point of my application.

Answer (score 1):

`position` property with value `fixed` can help you with the problem

```
html, body, #map {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     position: fixed;
}
```